# "telegram bot" и "ssl"

Tags: php, telegram-bot, ssl, telegram, php7

Есть два файла

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: vyach
 * Date: 30.03.2018
 * Time: 18:59
 */
include ('vendor/autoload.php');
class TelegramBot
{
    protected $token = "479283646:AAHTvTp9dyccPQza-i9K7vH0IgjLwaWSbLU";

    protected function query($method, $params = [])
    {
        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot";
        $url .= $this->token;
        $url .= "/" . $method; 
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => $url
         ]
        );

        $result = $client->request('GET');

        return json_decode($result->getBody());
    }

    public function getUpdates()
    {
        $response = $this->query('getUpdates');
        return $response->result;
    }

    public function sendMessage()
    {

    }
}
```

и второй

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: vyach
 * Date: 30.03.2018
 * Time: 18:42
 */

include ('vendor/autoload.php');
include ('TelegramBot.php');

//Получаем сообщения 
$telegramApi = new TelegramBot();

$updates = $telegramApi->getUpdates();

print_r($updates);
```

и вот ошибка

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\wamp64\www\MyFirstBot\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 186




 ( ! ) GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\wamp64\www\MyFirstBot\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 186
```

не знаю чем это поможет, но ещё есть такая информация

```
array (size=8)
  'default_cert_file' => string 'c:/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem' (length=25)
  'default_cert_file_env' => string 'SSL_CERT_FILE' (length=13)
  'default_cert_dir' => string 'c:/usr/local/ssl/certs' (length=22)
  'default_cert_dir_env' => string 'SSL_CERT_DIR' (length=12)
  'default_private_dir' => string 'c:/usr/local/ssl/private' (length=24)
  'default_default_cert_area' => string 'c:/usr/local/ssl' (length=16)
  'ini_cafile' => string '' (length=0)
  'ini_capath' => string '' (length=0)
```

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле php.ini пропишите пути к файлу CA-сертификатов для curl и openssl
Как я вижу путь к вашему файлу - "C:/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem" его и возьму.

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo = "C:/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem"

[openssl]
openssl.cafile = "C:/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem"
```

Если не поможет, то [загрузите этот пакет](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) и поменяйте на него путь

Comment: все это делал на windows, потом поставли ubuntu, повторил и все заработало., спасибо за помощь